# How do I replace randomly positioned 3 digit letter values with a number in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, dictionary

**EDIT: Resolved**

Sorry if this is a noob question, I tried Google, IRC, and asking around everywhere else after I couldn't figure it out myself after a considerable effort.

Anyway, I'm trying to replace month names with their value in my program. All the months are 3 letters long.

So I want to take Jan, Feb, .. Dec in other words and replace them with 01,02, .. 12

The problem is, they are placed in a big string right now with the rest of the date in numerical form and there is no exact distancing between months.

How do I do this?

Here's an viewable example of what I'm trying to do:

Say you have the string 
`'abcdefghijklmnop'`
where 
`'bcd','fgh', and 'nop' are values 01,02,and 03 respectively.`

I'd want to return the string as:

```
a01e02ijklm03
```

So far all I've been able to do is sort 3 letters at a time and test their value against a dictionary, but the second I hit a non-dictionary value (so nearly instantly) it gives me an error and stops.

Can anyone please help?

Broken code I just mentioned below:

```
#filterTwo changes month names into numbers (ex: Jan -> "01", Dec -> "02", ..)
month_dictionary = {
    'Jan':  "01",
    'Feb':  "02",
    'Mar':  "03",
    'Apr':  "04",
    'May':  "05",
    'Jun':  "06",
    'Jul':  "07",
    'Aug':  "08",
    'Sep':  "09",
    'Oct':  "10",
    'Nov':  "11",
    'Dec':  "12"
}

filterTwo = ''
words = []
for start in range(0, len(filterOne),3):
    words.append(filterOne[start:(start + 3)])
for word in words:
    filterTwo += "%s" % (month_dictionary[word])
print filterTwo
```

Comment: Why not just do a if check before just accessing the dict? `if word in month_dictionary: filterTwo += ...` I'm not sure your code is going to work though, you're checking every 3 characters like at index 0,3,6,9... but what if the month begins at index 2,4...?

Comment: Great idea on the first part, can't believe I didn't consider it, haha. As for the 2,4 index part you absolutely right as well, and I recognized that, but I'm unsure how to fix it. I wanted to post what I had regardless though to show I wasn't trying to get other people to do all the work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s = 'abcdefghijklmnop'
d = {'ab':'1', 'ij':'3'}
for i in d:
    s = s.replace(i, d[i])
```

Output

```
'1cdefgh3klmnop'
```

Comment: This looks like exactly I was looking for, thanks! I'm butchering the implentation at the moment, but I'm sure it's just a typo right now. Many thanks :)

Edit: Got it working, awesome! Great answer again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
for month_name,month_number in month_dictionary.items():
    filterOne.replace(month_name,month_number)
print filterOne
```